# monitor for docker stats similar to htop?

Tags: monitoring

I'm in the need for this and my google leaded me to [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40803050/248616)

I guess it's helpful to boost the beta for our sister site DevOps Stackexchagne here.

---

I quote the original question

`docker stats` gives a good overview of the cpu/mem/net io/disk io as text.

Does there exist a `htop` like monitor that shows the docker stats?

Comment: maybe this will work for you https://github.com/moncho/dry

Comment: I will give it a try

Answer (score 4):

bcicen on githup with tool `ctop` is working for me
ref. https://github.com/bcicen/ctop